# Upload file with hidden iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, iframe

I want to upload file without page refresh. ajaxSubmit() is not working because of other js in my project.

So, i want to use hidden iframe to upload file.

How will I implement this??

Thanks :)

Comment: Here is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1244-ColdFusion-jQuery-And-AJAX-File-Upload-Demo.htm The coldfusion side of it can easily be ported over to any other server-side language, it is very well commented.

Comment: I asked a question about this just a while ago and I updated and posted working code at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369726/jquery-file-upload-hidden-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by iframe? This is way to complicated try to use a mixture of HTML5 and Jquery.

Take a look at this [wonderful tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/)

Comment: You can use a standard upload system for IE8 users

Comment: Posting to a 0-sized iframe and having it call a javascript function in the parent on it's completion is supported though, and is really pretty simple.