# Jquery File Upload Hidden IFrame

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I needed a quick explanation on how to get an AJAX style file upload going using a hidden iframe. Here's the portion of the HTML code pertaining to the form:

```
<div id = "file" class = "info">        
    <form id="file_upload_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='script/uploadScript'>
        <input name="file" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
        <input id = "uploadSubmit" type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" />
        <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the relevant PHP:

```
public function uploadScript(){

    $returnVals = array();

    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        $returnVals['error'] =  "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }else{
        if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] != "text/plain"){
            $returnVals['error'] = "Badtype";
        }else{
            $returnVals['text'] =  file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($returnVals);
}
```

So, essentially, the PHP gets the file and checks if it's a text file. Then, I want to access the returned json within javascript. That's where I get confused...

```
$("#file_upload_form").submit(function() {
    $("#file_upload_form").target = "upload_target";
    $("#upload_target").onload = uploadDone();

});
```

Ideally, when the upload is complete and the iframe is loaded, this should call

```
function uploadDone() {
    alert($("#upload_target").contents().find("body").text());  
}
```

But, that's always blank. Essentially, the returnVals are placed into the iframe body, but after the alert, so the alert has nothing in it. So, is there a way to remedy this little flaw?

Is there any better explanation on how to do this? I've been banging my head against it with different sample codes and etc all day with no luck :/

I essentially want to be able to alert the text returned via the php code. Btw, I'm doing it this way because I want it to be able to work on IE7 and all browsers after.

I'd appreciate any help a ton. Thanks for the time!

Comment: what is the iframe for exactly?

Comment: Just as an aside, you have invalid html on this line: `<input id = "uploadSubmit"`; there isn't supposed to be a space between those characters.

Comment: The Iframe is there for an Ajax style upload. Essentially, I want to use the iframe to upload the file so the whole page doesn't have to load.

Comment: I think you must print/echo the json_encode($returnVals);
in the iframe (not return).

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I had return there. Haha, let me try that.

Comment: Okay, essentially, it looks like the onload event is being fired before the upload is finished. I just realized the string is in the body of the iframe, but it appears after the alert. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the string you get with your query. If it's empty, do nothing in that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've used something like that:

```
$("#upload_target")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML
```

... instead. But the general approach is similar: check this string, and if it's empty, just do nothing (i.e., return immediately). Otherwise proceed with analyzing this json.

Comment: The query actually works fine :/ the second time upload is pressed, the alert shows up with what should have been there after the first click.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely worked. I just had to remove the whole submit call, I think that was causing problems since I wasn't firing exactly on form submit.

Answer (score 1):

i use this code, and work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form#myform').submit(function(){
          $("#hiddenIframe").remove();    
          $('<iframe name="hiddenIframe" />').appendTo('body').attr({'id': 'hiddenIframe'});
          var Frame = $('#hiddenIframe');
          var newSrc = 'about:blank?nocache=' + Math.random(); //force new URL
          Frame.attr('src', newSrc); 
          var iframe = $('#hiddenIframe').load(function(){
              var response = iframe.contents().find('body').html();
              var txt = $.parseJSON(response);
              $('#message').append(txt.message);
              if(txt.error == false){
                   $.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '?myurl',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: {
                           //some data
                       },
                       success: function(data){
                           //some action
                       } 
                   });                                         
              }           
         });                                             
    });
});
```

This generate a new iframe on each submit, my PHP part

```
$this->message['error'] = true;
$this->message['message'] = "Problem!";

echo/print json_encode($this->message);
```

Try this

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually submit the hidden frame with the upload.  It creates a new iframe sets it to about:blank, then loads it's contents?