# How to upload a file through jQuery or AJAX with text data and save the file name in to SQL database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm writing a small PHP script to add some data in to a MySQL database. I'm using jQuery to send my text data to the processing PHP file which will put the data in to the MySQL data base that part is ok and working with out any issue.

But in this same form I need to upload a file to a folder in the server and save that path or the file name in to the database column "Img".

I've searched through the Stack site but didn't get any clue how to do this. If jQuery can't do this please tell me how to archive this with out loosing the text submission part. I'm going to list my code here.

My process PHP:

```
include ('connect.php');

$data = ("SELECT * FROM poiinfo");

$poiName = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$poiDes = $_REQUEST['Descrip'];
$poiCon = $_REQUEST['ConInfo'];
/*$poiImg = $_REQUEST['Image']; */ <-- my Image data but this is not the way need correct this

$dbData = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`Name`, `Des.`, `Contact`) VALUES ('$poiName','$poiDes','$poiCon')";

$putData = mysql_query($dbData);

if ($putData){
    echo "Data inserted";
}else {
    echo "Not Done";
}
```

My form:

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('connect.php');

$lastId = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM poiinfo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($lastId)){

    $nId = $row['ID'];
    $nId == "0";
    $nId = $nId++;

    mysql_quary("INSERT INTO poiinfo ('ID') VALUES ('$nId')");

}else {

    $lId = $row['ID'];
    $lId = $lId + 0;
    $lId++;
    $tId = $lId;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#save_data").click(function(){
    var name  = document.getElementById("Name").value;
    var desc = document.getElementById("Descrip").value;
    var con = document.getElementById("ConInfo").value;

    var dataString = 'Name='+name+'&Descrip='+desc+'&ConInfo='+con;
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      data:dataString,
      url:'AddPoiPro.php',
      success:function(data){
       if(data="Data inserted") {
          //alert("Data  Success");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: #060\">Data Saved</dive>";
          $('#msg').delay(1500).fadeOut();
        } else {
          //alert("Not Inserted");
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML= "<div style=\"background-color:#0F0; text-align:center; color: red\">Data Not Saved</div>";
        }
     } 
   });
  });
});
</script>

<title>AddPOI</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  <p>
    <label for="poiid">ID :</label>
    <input type="text" name="poiid" id="poiid" readonly="readonly" style="width:70px;" value="<?php echo $tId; ?>" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Name">POI Name :</label>

    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Descrip" style="alignment-adjust:middle">POI Description :</label>
    <textarea name="Descrip" id="Descrip" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="ConInfo">Contact Infomation :</label>
    <textarea name="ConInfo" id="ConInfo" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="Img">POI Image :</label>
    <!--<input type="file" name="Image" id="Image" /> --> <-- File upload place but for now it's commented out.
  </p>
  <p><div id="msg"></div></p>
  <p>  
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" id="save_data" value="Submit" style="width:100px;" />
    <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Rest Data" style="width:100px;" />
  </div>
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me as I said in most post's I saw that AJAX or jQuery can't handle the file upload so if there way to do it please educate me.

Also you guys are guru of coding I'm just a grasshopper so is this good coding or do I need to improve more on my style and also in the above form I have the ajax part in the header should I move it to another file and link it to the form.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot send files via AJAX, however you have several options that will achieve a similar effect. Either, use an iframe (I know this sounds old-fashioned but it works), or there are many HTML5 plugins you can use.

Comment: you can do this using uploadify try this out http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

Comment: @BenCarey thx for the quick reply can u just elaborate on how to use the iFrame method it's might be old but can be used so please sir.

Comment: @SadaruwanSamraweera Simply place the `file` field into an iframe with it s own form, and submit the form `onchange` of the file field. if it succeeds, then place the name of the uploaded file into a hidden field in the parent page

Comment: @BenCarey thx bro helpful to know old stuff as well as the new once.

Comment: @sourabhkasliwal I'm learning how to use the uploadify it's seems easy but I'm still facing the issue of storing the file name or the path in to the data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortuanately, for security reasons, you cannot upload a file via AJAX. (Can you imagine what would happen if JavaScript could access your file system?)

The way round this is to use a `form` with the `target` attribute set to an invisible `iframe`. This will achieve a file upload without refreshing the page.

You may find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369726/jquery-file-upload-hidden-iframe) useful.

Comment: Yeah that I can IE all over again.